# difference between simple controller and module controller in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter and I saw simple controller and module controller and I could not understand the difference between them.

I tried adding them both but I don't know how to use them more efficiently.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Module Controller can be used to run other [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers), for example if you have a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) which implements Login and you are creating a test assuming different groups of users which need to be logged in - you can call the aforementioned "Transaction Controller" using the Module Controller in 2 different Thread Groups instead of copying and pasting it.

  [image: JMeter Module Controller]

  See [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) article for more information.
- Simple Controller actually does nothing apart from grouping [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers). You might use Simple Controller in the Module Controller or apply a single [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), [Pre-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#preprocessors), etc. to all Simple Controller's children. Apart from these two use cases it doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Controller is just a container to group samplers in it and apply some scoping rules for example:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller

Module Controller is a way to reuse code accross your test:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller

Answer (score 1):

Module controller can be used to choose between Simple Controllers see [example](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/10/jmeter-module-controller-example.html?m=1)

> Module controller will allow me to run only selected simple controller's requests.